# Безопасность схемы шифрования

Tags: python-3.x, безопасность, хеширование

Небольшое введение. Создал с приятелями небольшой мессенджер. Дали волю паранойе и скомбинировали несколько разных схем для хранения данных.
Проект будет проходить конкурс, а потому на всякий случай решили сменить метод хранения логинов и паролей, а заодно узнать, насколько безопасна предыдущая схема. Собственно, вот...
**Для логина и пароля разрешено использовать только символы a-z,A-Z и 0-9**

```
`seq={'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2,  '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, 
     'a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 12, 'd': 13, 'e': 14, 'f': 15, 'g': 16, 'h': 17, 'i': 18, 'j': 19, 'k': 20, 'l': 21, 'm': 22, 'n': 23, 'o': 24, 'p': 25, 'q': 26, 'r': 27, 's': 28, 't': 29, 'u': 30, 'v': 31, 'w': 32, 'x': 33, 'y': 34, 'z': 35, 
     'A': 36, 'B': 37, 'C': 38, 'D': 39, 'E': 40, 'F': 41, 'G': 42, 'H': 43, 'I': 44, 'J': 45, 'K': 46, 'L': 47, 'M': 48, 'N': 49, 'O': 50, 'P': 51, 'Q': 52, 'R': 53, 'S': 54, 'T': 55, 'U': 56, 'V': 57, 'W': 58, 'X': 59, 'Y': 60, 'Z': 61}
def log_in(login, password):
    login=input('Login: ')
    password=input("Password: ")
    answer=0
    nick=0
#переводим строки логина и пароля в десятичную систему счисления(подразумевается, что до этого они находились в шестидесятидвоичной)
    for i in range(0, len(password)):
        answer+=(62**i)*seq[password[len(password)-1-i]]
    for i in range(0, len(login)):
        nick+=(62**i)*seq[login[len(login)-1-i]]
    nick=hex(nick)[2::]
#переводим "число" логина в шестнадцатеричную систему
    answer=str(answer).encode('utf-8')
#переводим "число" пароля в байтовую строку
    answer=sha512(answer).hexdigest()+nick
#получаем хэш SHA512 от answer и "подсаливаем" его преобразованным логином
    answer=str(answer).encode('utf-8')
#переводим получившуюся строку в байтовую
    sha=sha1(answer).hexdigest()
#получаем от нее хэш SHA1
`
```

И уже этот результат хранится на сервере, а при авторизации программа проводит эти же вычисления и отправляет их на сервер, где происходит сравнение(есть в базе или нет)
Насколько безопасна такая схема хранения данных в случае утечки, гм, части базы данных?
P.S: Вся суть этих преобразований в том, что логин и пароль никак не связаны. Т.е. на сервере не хранятся пары вида "логин-шифрованный пароль". Хранятся лишь хэши, называемые пользовательскими ключами.
P.P.S: Возня с `for`-ами нужна для того, чтобы даже если кто-то попытается взломать хэш и восстановить пароль, он бы получил лишь не очень понятное число.

Comment: mschap2 посмотрите, он намного лучше обычного соленого хеша и не подвержен "человек посередине"

В Вашем коде можно выкинуть форы, они не дают ничего кроме тормозов сервера. Это от утечки базы хешей сделанно? нет смысла подмешивать ник, ведь он там рядом лежит.

Comment: Безопасность сводится к sha1-хэшу от sha512-хэша от пароля, а всё остальное всего лишь незначительно замедляющие рюшечки. Безопасность сводится к скорости перебора, и перебрать пароли длиной до 9 символов будет очень легко на игровой видеокарте

Comment: «он бы получил лишь не очень понятное число» — во-первых, это предполагает, что алгоритм взломщику будет не известен, а почему вы решили, что он будет не известен? Во-вторых, он догадается сопоставить числа символам и рано или поздно вычислит ваш `seq` даже если не сможет прочитать его из кода (а почему вы решили, что взломщик не сможет прочитать его из кода?)

Comment: Ну а логин чаще всего и так известен, и его подбирать не надо. Думаю, ни для кого не секрет, что мой логин — andreymal :)

Comment: То есть, суть этой схемы только в том, чтобы вытащить условный хэш пароля из записи пользователя и поместить их все в отдельную таблицу без явного сопоставления с самими пользователями? А "хэшу пароля", присланному от клиента, просто верить и проверять его существование среди всех вместо того, чтобы сравнивать с конкретным?

Comment: В этом состоит одна из главных проблем безопасности- хранение сообщений без вероятности "перепутать" аккаунты, к которым они относятся.
А все, что связано с пользовательскими данными, ссылается на т.н. токен пользователя, т.е. результат вычислений, представленных выше

Comment: Зря я комментарий отредактировал. Для истории: там был вопрос о том, как сообщения связываются с их авторами. Окей, то есть, сервер имеет возможность прислать сообщение только с ключом, но не хранит читаемого "логина"/"ника" для сообщений, получается? Как тогда собеседники будут узнавать сообщения конкретного человека? Хранить сопоставление ключа и логина каждый у себя? В какой момент они получат информацию, чтобы это сопоставление у себя сохранить и при этом не повредить безопасности "пользовательского ключа"?

Comment: Хм. @D-side, я не против( и даже "за") дискуссии/обсуждения на эту тему, но не уверен, что это следует делать в комментариях. Мы можем обсудить это еще где-нибудь?

Comment: В ответ на пространные дискуссии обычно система предлагает перейти в чат, но это почему-то до сих пор не произошло. Возможно, после этого комментария предложит? (UPD: не-а)

Comment: @D-side, печально. Собственно, что за чат? Просто де-факто я на SO примерно неделю и многое не знаю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79736/discussion-between---and-d-side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по тому материалу, который я успел изучить за это время, данная схема является условно безопасной.

## Аргументы "за"

1)По значению хэш-функции нельзя однозначно восстановить исходную строку, так как поле значений хэш-функций хоть и велико, но конечно, в отличии от бесконечного количества уникальных строк. И, следовательно, для каждого хэша существует бесконечность строк, имеющие такой же хэш. А в данном случае ситуация усложняется тем, что используются две разных по длине и алгоритму хэш-функции.
2)Нигде не хранятся логины в "чистом" виде(при условии, конечно же, что логин для авторизации не является еще и никнеймом)
3)Одновременно решается проблема с "подсаливанием" хэшей и хранением логинов
4)Хотя примененные средства для защиты и не являются достаточно надежными, чтобы не имело смысла взламывать их, они достаточно сильно задержат взломщика, чтобы успеть вмешаться

## Аргументы "против"

1)Функция SHA1, равно как и функции семейства SHA2, достаточно давно признаны небезопасными и условно легко взламываемыми(уж SHA1- так точно)
2)Если злоумышленник получит доступ к базе данных, он может просто изменить её содержимое так, что она станет абсолютно бесполезна. Или, к примеру, заменит все хэши в БД на случайные строки
3)Любой, кто реально захочет её взломать, рискует умереть от смеха, вызванного наивностью алгоритма и фактом, что его реально кто-то использует